# access children page's title from masterpage aspx

Tags: .net, page-title

I have a bunch of child pages relating to the same masterpage in `VB.NET`.

Now I need to update database records depending upon child page's title, and since the code-behind is the same for each page in the project, I want to put that stuff in the master page.

Each page have its own `title="myOwnTitle"` property like this: `<Page%@ Page Title="Test Page"`

But when I write a script on the masterpage level like:

```
Dim varTitle = me.Title
```

The value that is actually returned is the masterpage title (of course you'd say :-)

Is there a SIMPLE solution to access the children page from master?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it have to be in the master page?  When I have common tasks to do in each child page then I make a new class that inherits from Page and use that for my children pages.

Public Class NewPage
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

```
'Do some stuff here
```

End Sub

End Class

Comment: But this means you can't have your "do some stuff here" script written in one place only!... Maybe I should use script that I put in app.code folder then... That would be the solution.

Comment: No you'd only have it in one place, in your sub-classed page and then you'd use that class in place of the normal system.web.ui.page.  I do a lot of work with altering themes on the fly in child-pages so I have all my logic for that in a single sub-classed Page class so I don't have to repeat it in every child page.

Answer (score 0):

try using  `Dim varTitle = this.Title`

or if you are using a script

```
var title = window.title
```